# gaps within menu tabs?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, whitespace

Why do I have gaps between my tabs?

[image]

my css for each tab is:

```
    .tab1
{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 110px;
    width: 234px;
    background-image: url("../images/first-tab.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.tab2
{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 110px;
    width: 234px;
    background-image: url("../images/second-tab.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.tab3
{
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 110px;
    width: 234px;
    background-image: url("../images/last-tab.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your tabs are `inline-block` and thuis treated almost the same as `inline` wich means theres whitespace between them id theres' whitespace (spaces, tabs or linebreaks) between them in the html-source.

this will give you "gaps":

```
<div class="tab1">Content here</div>
<div class="tab2">Content here</div>
<div class="tab3">Content here</div>
```

this won't:

```
<div class="tab1">Content here</div><div class="tab2">Content here</div><div class="tab3">Content here</div>
```

and this also won't:

```
<div class="tab1">
    Content here
</div><div class="tab2">
    Content here
</div><div class="tab3">
    Content here
</div>
```

to change this, update your html-source and remove the whitespace or (better) change your css to use `block`-elements and `float:left` (wich *may* lead to other problems, but thats hard to say since you havn't give your html-sourcecode)

Answer (score 0):

Since they are inline block they display a single text space between them if there is actual whitespace between them in the html, so either remove the whitespace in the html(ugly html) or think of another solution to display your elements this way(floating for example).

Answer (score -1):

What html are you using? Most elements have default paddings/margins. You will have to override these in most cases. Try "margin:0;padding:0;" to remove them or add your html-example.